# Tooltip on custom options (Magento 2)

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1, custom-options

A lot of my products have custom options.

The `255 character limit` in the custom options is not enough to properly describe some of them.

**What I want to do is to have a tooltip for my custom options.**

I have searched like crazy for an extension that will do this, but all I've found so far is image tooltips.

Does anyone know how I can pull this off?

Comment: Have you found anything that helped you?

Comment: Unfortunately, no.  Still looking for a solution.

Comment: Please review this https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/192994/applying-magento-2-library-tooltip-to-custom-theme/192998#192998 I think it will help you.

Comment: Have you searched for a paid extension? this vendor has recently released an updated version of [custom options extension](https://www.itoris.com/magento-2-custom-options.html) and included tooltips for options.